# Large array returned from scipy integrate quad

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

everyone. I was trying to compute an integral numerically using scipy.quad. However, it returns a really huge array with no other error. Can anyone see the problem? The code works very fine with simple integral like 
quad(lambda x:x**2,0,4)
but for the code below
try a=20,b=20,c=20,j=1 you get a really huge list of result with repeating numbers

```
def Lj(a,b,c,j):
    R1=a
    R2=b
    R3=c
    if j==1:
        Rj=a
    elif j==2:
        Rj=b
    elif j==3:
        Rj=c
    else:
        raise ValueError('j needs to be an integer between 1 and 3')

    result = (R1*R2*R3)*quad(lambda s: 1/((s+Rj**2)*sqrt(((s+R1**2)*(s+R2**2)*(s+R3**2))))/2, 0, inf)
    return result
```

[image]

Comment: Did you forget to post some code? Please post exact code which displays the problem and and exact traceback/output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`quad`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) returns a tuple containing the integral and an estimate of the error.  You multiply this tuple by `R1*R2*R3`, which replicates the tuple `R1*R2*R3` times.

To fix this, use just the first value returned by `quad`.  That is, replace this:

```
result = (R1*R2*R3)*quad(lambda s: 1/((s+Rj**2)*sqrt(((s+R1**2)*(s+R2**2)*(s+R3**2))))/2, 0, inf)
```

with something like this:

```
intgrl, err = quad(lambda s: 1/((s+Rj**2)*sqrt(((s+R1**2)*(s+R2**2)*(s+R3**2))))/2, 0, inf)
result = (R1*R2*R3)*intgrl
```